# gmail imap: get recently updated messages

Tags: python, imap

is it any way (with IMAP)  to retrieve *only* updated messages for some period of time? (or, perhaps, only their flags).
what i mean, with example:
i've checked my mbox with `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(...)` at 4.00pm;
at 4.15pm i've gone to gmail web interface and marked one of my mails as "read";
at 4.30pm i want to check all updates in my mail box, for period in 4.01-now, through `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

For vanilla IMAP, you're out of luck.  But if the IMAP server supports the CONDSTORE extension, you can do this.  See [RFC 4551 section 3.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4551#section-3.3.1) for the details.  Generally, it involves keeping track of the folder's `HIGHESTMODSEQ` value and issuing a command like

```
A001 UID FETCH 1:* (FLAGS) (CHANGEDSINCE 12345)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IMAP servers record when flags are set, just the fact they are set. I cant see anything the RFC that suggests otherwise. http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html
I would suggest you would have to retrieve and store a list of messages, and use that for comparison the next time you fetch.